# How can I use mvn verify command?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing

I need an example of how can I apply and use the command "**mvn verify**"
I have Eclipse and Maven library.
I also created all test files.
Now I want to use `mvn verify` so where can I run this command?
From which screen or window? Is it from Eclipse or from cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify is just another build lifecycle in maven so you can run it in command line from within the directory of your pom.xml file like any other maven command .
If you want to run it from eclipse navigate to Run >> Run Configuration menu, select Maven build from left sidebar and make your own maven build. In order to have Maven build section you need M2Eclipse plugin added to Eclipse.

Comment: how can I create mvn verify from these menus

Comment: @MuradAlHaj This link has a very detailed guide for creating a custom launch configuration: 
https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/maven/launch-maven4myeclipse-maven-run-setup-tutorial/